# Postgresql - LEFT JOIN error

Tags: postgresql, join

Apologies ahead of time for the novice question as I am working through building my first database. I've come to joining my tables (I have multiple), but have decided to test one first. I am trying to join the 'creative table' with the 'skills' table (this table with have 3 other linked tables later). The tables and code I'm using are as followed:

[image]

[image]

```
SELECT
    creative.creative_key,
    creative.creative_type,
    skills.skills_id
FROM creative
    LEFT JOIN skills ON creative.creative_key = skills.creative_key;
```

but I am getting errors such as

> ERROR:  column skills.creative_key does not exist
>   LINE 7: LEFT JOIN skills ON creative.creative_key = skills.creative...

I am honestly confused on why there are periods between tables names and columns. How can I get this join to work, please!

Thank you ahead of time - and be gentle, I'm learning.

Comment: Please include the table definitions for both tables so we can see what columns are available in both tables. Without this information we can't give any advice on the issue.

Comment: Thank you, Joe. Wasn't sure how to create the tables I often see with examples, so I had to go back to copy/paste for my example.

Comment: I would like to help you but since you posted them as images and my work blocks imgur I am unable to provide any further assistance.

Comment: I appreciate it - when I tried to do it in text, the alignment was way off. This is only my second question, so I'm getting used to this too.
I got the the statement to take using:

 SELECT * FROM creative LEFT JOIN skills on creative .creative _key = skills.skills_id;

But now I need to figure out how to do the same with the other three tables that need to be joined to skills.

I appreciate you trying!

Comment: Please provide *text* instead of the image. *Ideally* provide `CREATE TABLE` statements in addition to sample values as `INSERT`statements. It's the canonical, least ambiguous form, and we can readily recreate & test the scenario. And *always* disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear: there is no column `creative_key` in the table `skills` - and I believe Postgres more than your images. You might think you have created the table with that column, but clearly you have not. That's why we need the original `CREATE TABLE` statement of at least the `skills` table. Ideally both tables. Re "the alignment was off" - highlight the code, then click on the `{}` in the editor toolbar. You can find more information about formatting by clicking on the `?` button in the upper right corner when you [edit] your question.

Comment: put 4 spaces at the start of each line of pasted text and then it will not be mangled.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the field in the table is spelled correctly?  If the system says a field does not exist, then in my experience it means someone misspelled something.

Also, please include the field type (int, char, etc) in your question instead of the "auto-increment".  That info doesn't really matter, whereas the field type sometimes is useful.  And if you have to post an image, post it of your tables and fields from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the schema and table names are in small letters only. If any one of them are in the capital that then you have to use "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLENAME"  only

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).